# Login facebook abrindo sozinho em aplicação android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Estou criando uma aplicação android que faz login com facebook. Isto já está funcionando, mas está acontecendo algo que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Segundo os exemplos da própria documentação do facebook, o código que faz as chamadas pra api do facebook fica dentro do método `onCreate()`, e isso faz com que assim que eu abra a página de login (que tem o botão de login com facebook) ele já abre automaticamente o facebook pra pedir as permissões mesmo sem eu ter clicado no botão de fazer login com facebook.

O que eu faço para que ele só abra a tela de login quando eu clicar no botão de "Log in with Facebook"?

Seguem os códigos:

#### LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

CallbackManager callbackManager;
LoginButton loginButton;
LoginManager loginManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Log.d("Teste", "onCreate inicio");

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Log.d("Teste", "onSuccess inicio [Token = " + loginResult.getAccessToken() + "], [Permissões = " + loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions() +
                    "], [Negações = " + loginResult.getRecentlyDeniedPermissions() + "] Json: "+ loginResult.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.d("Teste", "onCancel inicio");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.d("Teste", "onError( " + exception.toString() + ")");
        }
    });


}
```

#### activity_login.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#F76B03"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:gravity="center">

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="ou"
    android:textColor="#000000" />


<EditText style="@style/tvFullParent"
    android:id="@+id/etLogin"
    android:background="@drawable/shapeedittext"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_user"
    android:hint="E-mail"/>

<EditText style="@style/tvFullParent"
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:background="@drawable/shapeedittext"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_lock_closed"
    android:hint="Senha"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:text="@string/btnLogin"/>
```

#### androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi da [documentação](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3), no `onCreate` você cria e realiza todos os registros, assim como você já fez, mas o método `logInWithReadPermissions` é a chamada para a ação que realiza de fato a autenticação, porém, somente quando você não utiliza o `LoginButton` e sim algum botão customizado, assim você coloca este método no `OnClickListener`.

É o que diz neste trecho, logo antes da indicação deste método:

> Then you can later perform the actual login, such as in a custom
>   button's **OnClickListener**:

Como não é o seu caso, já que você está utilizando o `LoginButton`, você pode eliminar esta linha e deixar que o próprio botão execute o seu método de autenticação ao ser pressionado.